# Step Response RC Circuit: Current at Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, resistors, switches, circuit-analysis

I have a problem understanding why is that ic=0 at t<0 if the switch is closed for a long and only opened for t=0?

My friend told me that at t<0, the ic will always be 0A regardless whether the switch is open or closed. Is this true?

[image]

Comment: If the switch is closed for a long time, iC is 0 because the capacitor will be fully charged (as charged as it'll ever be). If the switch is open for a long time, iC is 0 because the capacitor will be fully discharged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is correct.  No current flows through the capacitor without some change in voltage across that capacitor.  That change - in this circuit - only happens when the switch changes state.

When the switch is closed (for a 'long time'), the capacitor is fully charged.  It has a voltage across it that doesn't change until the switch is opened.  Once the switch is opened, the capacitor charge now has to supply i<sub>r</sub>, so the voltage across the cap begins to decrease.

In the other case, when the switch is open for a long time and then closed, the capacitor initially has 0V across it and the switch closing allows the capacitor to charge.  Given enough time in this state, you will have the first condition again.

Answer (score 1):

When we say that the switch has been closed (open) for a long time, we mean that enough time has passed that any transients have decayed to insignificance, i.e., the circuit voltages and currents are no longer changing with time.  This state of affairs is known as *DC steady state*.

Now, recall that the current through a capacitor is proportional to the rate of change of the voltage across:

$$i_C = C \frac{dv_C}{dt}$$

So, if the voltages in the circuit are not changing with time, the current through the capacitor in the circuit must be zero.

It follows that, if the switch has been closed (open) for a long time, the capacitor current is zero.

Immediately after the switch changes state, the circuit begins to transition to a new steady state solution and so, for some period of time, the voltages and currents change with time but, eventually, the transients decay away leaving the circuit voltages and currents once again constant and the capacitor current zero.